# Copy the contents of one column to another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

The following jQuery is extremely slow (~7 sec). I'm clearly doing it the wrong way!

I'm trying to copy the contents of column `col` to column `0` in an HTML table
so if col is 2, then I need to copy column 2 to column 0.

```
for (var i=0;i<31;i++)
  $('.grid tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:first-child').text(
    $('.grid tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(' + col + ')').text()
   );
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>D</td><td>G</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td><td>E</td><td>H</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td><td>F</td><td>I</td></tr>
  <!-- etc. -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to select each table cell individually.  You can select the source column and destination columns and iterate over them:

```
// Get the target column table cells.  This will select the first cell from
// each row in the table.
var target = $('.grid tr td:first-child');

// Iterate over each cell in the source column and copy its text to the
// corresponding cell in the target column.
$('.grid tr td:nth-child(' + (col + 1) + ')').each(function (rowIndex) {
    target.slice(rowIndex, rowIndex + 1).text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Whoops, had the source and target swapped originally.  Fixed.

Comment: Cool beans. This works if I change `slice` to `eq`. Out of interest, why was my original code so slow?

Comment: Oh, I left off the 2nd parameter for slice().  Fixed.

Comment: Your original code was selecting each source and destination cell individually, which meant a lot more DOM traversal for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Another option.  Not sure which would run faster.  I simply removed the first column, since it was going to be replaced, then prepended the column of choice:

```
col = 2;
$('.grid td:first-child').remove();
$('.grid td:nth-child('+(--col)+')').each(function(){
    $(this).parent('tr').prepend('<td>'+$(this).text()+'</td>');
});
```

Check it out: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/US2wp/).