# Adding column to table with value from previous column in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm new in jquery and found this site as more helpful then others. I'm faced  problem adding column to the table. The added column should have consist the value from previous column. Here is code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3sEGf/27/.

HTML:

```
 <table border="1" class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
        <th>Repository</th>
        <th> File 1</th>

        <th><button  class="addColumn">Add Column</button></th></tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Publish date</td><td>2/14/2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Project</td><td id="two"><select id="select1">
<option value="">Pick one</option>
<option value="1">False</option>
<option value="2">True</option>
</select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Title</td><td>Some info</td>
         </tr>  
</tbody>         
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table.table button.addColumn").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $table = $this.closest('table')
    var columnName = window.prompt("Enter Column name", "");

    $('<th>' + columnName +'</th>').insertBefore($table.find('tr').first().find('th:last'))

     var contentvalue = $(this).find("td:first").html();    

     $('<td>' + contentvalue + '</td>').insertAfter($table.find('tr:gt(0)').find('td:last'))

}); });
```

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898337/copy-the-contents-of-one-column-to-another-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $table=$("table.table")


    $("table.table button.addColumn").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $table = $this.closest('table'),
            $rows = $table.find('tbody tr')
            var columnName = window.prompt("Enter Column name", "");

        $('<th>' + columnName + '</th>').insertBefore($table.find('tr').first().find('th:last'))

        $rows.each(function () {
            var $last = $(this).find('td:last');

            $(this).append($last.clone())
        })


    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3sEGf/32/)**</kbd>

Comment: Did you notice even entering Repository in prompt this clone same as file 1

Comment: @C-link huh? no idea what that means

Comment: when you click then in prompt type "Repository" then it is being displayed the same as of "File 1" column.

Comment: i got impression from OP that is what is wanted. Essentially duplicate column html with new heading text